# Rearranging power series expansion to get parameter on denominator

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

How can we rearrange

$$T=\dfrac{k V+g}{gk}\bigg(kT-\dfrac{1}{2}k^{2}T^{2}+\dfrac{1}{6}k^{3}T^{3}\bigg),$$

to get

$$T=\dfrac{2V/g}{1+k V/g}+\dfrac{1}{3}k T^{2}$$
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, $$kT-\frac12k^2T^2+\frac16k^3T^3=\frac{gTk}{kV+g}=\frac{Tk}{\frac{kV}g+1}$$

$$\implies 1-\frac12kT+\frac16k^2T^2=\frac1{\frac{kV}g+1} \text{Cancelling out } Tk\text{ assuing } Tk\ne0$$

$$\implies 1-\frac1{\frac{kV}g+1}=\frac12kT-\frac16k^2T^2 $$

$$\implies \frac{\frac{kV}g}{\frac{kV}g+1}=\frac12kT-\frac16k^2T^2 $$

Multiply both sides with $\frac2k,$ $$ \frac{\frac{2V}g}{\frac{kV}g+1}= T-\frac13kT^2  $$

Now,make the required side change